# Runs of negative values

Tags: list-manipulation, data

The City of Edmonton, close to where I live,  just set a record for the number of consecutive days the min. temp was below zero  (167 and counting...)

I found a site to download weather data for Edmonton  https://edmonton.weatherstats.ca/download.html

My question is,  once I get a list of temps into Mathematica,  how would I check for "long" runs of negative values.  I.E.  If I had 10 years of min. temp values in a list,  how would I find the longest list of values that are all below zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep) to convert negative numbers to 0 and positive numbers to 1. Then, you are just looking for the longest run of 0s. There are several answers for this, but I couldn't find a canonical version to point to after a brief look. So, here is a function that does this for you:

```
longestNegativeSequenceLength[v_]:=With[{bool = UnitStep[v]},
    Max[
        Length /@ Split[bool][[bool[[1]]+1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]
    ]
]
```

For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20]

longestNegativeSequenceLength[data]
```

> {0.634779, -0.777161, 0.579052, -0.624394, -0.517278, -0.868522, 0.0844932, -0.537691, -0.207988, 0.400948, -0.576348, 0.497314, -0.154299, -0.50501, 0.954344, 0.650326, 0.85055, 0.156112, -0.414261, -0.583898}
>
> 3

**Addendum**

To address the actual question of finding the sequence of negative values, you could do:

```
longestNegativeSequence[v_] := Module[{split = SplitBy[v, Negative]},
    First @ MaximalBy[split[[If[v[[1]]<0, 1, 2] ;; -1 ;; 2]], Length]
]

longestNegativeSequence[data]
```

> {-0.624394, -0.517278, -0.868522}

Comment: The answers were, as always, instructive and helpful.   Yes... based on a sample of 10000 days of weather data,  we are (currently) at 167 days with a min. temp that is below zero.

Answer (score 7):

In version 11.3 we have [`SequenceSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html) which is good for this:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20];

MaximalBy[Length] @ SequenceSplit[data, {_?Positive ..}]

(* {{-0.624394, -0.517278, -0.868522}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Carl Woll's answer is instructive, but I think for people newer to Mathematica using the sequence functions would seem clearer and more direct.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20];

threshold = 0;
pos = SequencePosition[If[# < threshold, 1, 0] & /@ data, {1 ..}];
data[[Span @@ #]] & /@ Take[Reverse@SortBy[pos, #[[2]] - #[[1]] &], 3]

(* {{-0.624394, -0.517278, -0.868522}, {-0.414261, -0.583898}, {-0.154299, -0.50501}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice little oneliner without `SequenceSplit` is

```
First@MaximalBy[Length]@Select[Negative@*First]@SplitBy[#, Sign] &
```

Sadly there's no operator form of `SplitBy`, otherwise it would be a lovely litle point-free definition.